# Why will javascript only output the last string in array?

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and have come across something I don't understand

Why does javascript only output the last string of the array into the `<ul>` id but outputs the full array length in the console?

```js
var ul = document.getElementById('id');
var colours = ["red", "green", "blue"];

var i;
for (i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
  console.log(colours[i])
  ul.innerHTML = "<li>" + colours[i] + "</li>";
}
```

```html
<ul id="id"></ul>
```

Comment: Because you're overwriting the content of `ul` everytime you do `ul.innerHTML = ...`. Should be `+=` instead of `=`

Comment: `document.getElementById('id').innerHTML= ["red", "green", "blue"].map(colour => \`<li>${colour}</li>\`).join("")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the colours element to the ul element. Try this.

```
var ul = document.getElementById('id');
var colours = ["red", "green", "blue"];

var i;
for (i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
    console.log(colours[i])
    ul.innerHTML += "<li>" + colours[i] + "</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are overwriting your DOM element at each step of the loop. It just successively takes all the values.

If you need all the values, what you can do is adding them instead of overwrite them:

```
var content = "";
for (i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
  console.log(colours[i])
  content += "<li>" + colours[i] + "</li>";
}
ul.innerHTML = content
```